# UWP Single App Kiosk - How to activate Online Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, uwp, microphone, capability

I'm currently facing an issue using the onScreen Keyboard on an UWP Assigned Access app.

In fact, when I'm using this feature on my own user session I can easily access the dictation feature to fill my textbox' using my voice, but when I'm launching my Single-App Kiosk session, I can access the touch keyboard but the dictation option disappeared.

By the way, I'd already activated the microphone capability in my manifest and toggled on the microphone sharing options for this app in the privacy settings.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue and found a solution ?

This is my virtual keyboard on my own session :
[image]

And this is the Single-App Kiosk session :
[image]

Both copy & paste and dictation options disappeared

**EDIT :**

After some investigations I noticed that the Online Speech Recognition is only activated for my own session when I toggle it on. So the new question used to be : "**How to activate Online Speech Recognition for Single-App Kiosk ?**"

Comment: I tested with touch keyboard, but i could not reproduce above issue, could you mind make screen record to explain it?

Comment: Sure, I just added two screenshot to show you the difference between two launching modes

Comment: *when I'm launching my assigned access session, I can access the touch keyboard but the dictation option disappeared* what's mean of assigned access session?

Comment: We are launching this UWP app through a Single-App Kiosk using the Assigned Access feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that there is no way in UWP that could launch the setting page and enable the
Speech Recognition function in a Kiosk mode. This is the limitation of Kiosk mode.